# How is JSON/XML transmitted?

Tags: xml, json, asp.net-mvc

I have my MVC Web service:

```
public class PersonApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>() {
            new Person(){Name="Rahul", Age =29, Sex = "M"},
            new Person(){Name="Chinmoy", Age = 28, Sex = "M"},
            new Person(){Name="Charu", Age = 27, Sex = "F"}
            };

        return lstPerson;
    }
}
```

In the client side generate this XML: (327 char without space)

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestJson.Models">
    <Person>
        <Age>29</Age>
        <Name>Rahul</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Age>28</Age>
        <Name>Chinmoy</Name>
        <Sex>M</Sex>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Age>27</Age>
        <Name>Charu</Name>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

I thought in create a reduce Version using alias for attributes (245 without space or 75% original size):

```
<ArrayOfP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestJson.Models">
    <P>
        <A>29</A>
        <N>Rahul</N>
        <S>M</S>
    </P>
    <P>
        <A>28</A>
        <N>Chinmoy</N>
        <S>M</S>
    </P>
    <P>
        <A>27</A>
        <N>Charu</N>
        <S>F</S>
    </P>
</ArrayOfP>
```

I really dont know how that work behing scene. My question are what happen when you are handling bigger list, especially thinking in mobile device where bandwidth is reduce.

a) Do MVC web service generate some conversion table or schema description so instead of sending 1000 times the string `<age>` send `<a>`

b) What about numbers? are they send as bytes or string. Specially for the case of float like lat / lon coordinates. Two coordinates mean 8 bytes but a string is like 20 bytes `-67.051315, 9.988972`

c) My hope is MVC do it that for me, otherwise I should create more simplify version and do the parsing in the client side. Of course this version is difficult to read, but only have 188 char or 57% original size.

```
<ArrayOfP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestJson.Models">
    <P>29|Rahul|M</P>
    <P>28|Chinmoy|M</P>
    <P>27|Charu|F</P>
</ArrayOfP>
```

d) Is there a way I can measure the Json/Xml package size. As you see I can only measure the data transmitted as string length. But is that the size in bytes transmitted for the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API service will return json or xml, depending on Accept header of your client. If it's "text/xml", it will return xml. If it's "application/json", it will return json.

Usually xml is not optimized, but often response in these cases compressed with zip/gzip. See your server settings for that. It takes additional CPU time, but if you care about traffic, you can consider this option.

Numbers are sent as strings. All other types - depending on serializer (for instance, binary data will be serialized to base64 string representation). You can create your own serializer and serialize them as you want. But keep in mind that if your client accepts text/xml, it could be a bad practice to serialize numbers as binary data.

Summarizing: use gzip compression on the server.

Comment: Ok, That is what I tought. So if i use gZip then I shouldn't bother to replace `<AGE>` for `<A>`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza exactly, compression will do much better job than strings replacement. And it will keep things easier to understand.